# Meaning of "Toffy Circles"

Tags: meaning, books

I'm reading [*"The Demolished Man"*](http://www.arthursbookshelf.com/sci-fi/bester/demolish.htm) by Alfred Bester, and came across a sentence I could not understand (in bold):

> "No you don't, Mr. Powell." Mary burst into laughter. "So that's it. You want me for a chaperone. Victorian word, isn't? So are you, Linc. Positively atavistic."  
>   "I brand that as a lie. **In toffy circles I'm known as the most progressive**---"  
>   "And what's that image? Oh. Knights of the Round Table. Sir Galahad Powell. And there's something underneath that. I---" Suddenly she stopped laughing and turned pale.

What is the meaning of that sentence? Best I could find, **toffy** is another spelling for **toffee**, but then what are toffy circles?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In British slang, a [toff](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=toff#T5270600) is "a rich or upper-class person." Toffy appears to be the adjective form of this word, so the phrase presumably means "rich or upper-class groups of people."

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of "toff". I suspected it has a similar meaning to "tea party" or "book club", so I naturally looked for a noun...

Answer (score 4):

"Toffy" may refer to the English slang "toff", meaning a pretentious person.  And "circles" probably refers to a group of people.

Answer (score 2):

*[Toffy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toffy)* is an alternative spelling of *toffee*. By itself, *[toffee](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toffee#Noun)* refers to  “a type of confectionery made by boiling sugar (or treacle, etc) with butter or milk”.  However, the commonly-used combination *[toffee-nosed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toffee-nosed)* is an adjective meaning “snobbish, condescending or aloof”.  Wiktionary shows the combination's etymology as “Probably from toff”, a *[toff](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/toff)* being  “A person of the upper class- or high-class-pretence who usually communicates an air of superiority”.

Wiktionary shows no etymology for *toff*, but OED1 (1926) shows:

> Toff *vulgar.* Also *rarely* toft. [Perh. a
>   vulgar perversion of TUFT, as formerly applied to
>   a nobleman or gentleman-commoner at Oxford.]
>   An appellation given by the lower classes to a
>   person who is stylishly dressed or who has a smart
>   appearance; a swell; hence, one of the well-to-do,
>   a 'nob' ...
>   Hence Toffish, Toffy *adjs.* like or characteristic
>   of a 'toff', stylish.

OED1 entries under the *toffee, toffy* heading refer only to candy.  The etymology is obscure:

> Toffee, toffy  [Of uncertain origin:
>   app. orig. dialectal, and sometimes spelt *tuffy,
>   toughy*, as if named from its toughness; but the
>   earlier form is the northern TAFFY, q. v.]

The OED1 (1919) entry for *taffy* shows no etymology for its “candy” and “soft soap” senses:

> Taffy¹  The earlier form of TOFFEE, now Scotch, North Eng., and American.
>   1. A sweetmeat made from sugar or treacle, with butter, etc. : see TOFFEE. ...
>   2. *U. S. slang.* Crude or vulgar compliment or flattery;  'soft soap'; blarney. ...
>   3. *attrib.* and *Comb.*, as *taffy stand, stick*; taffy-join, a reunion of young people for the making of taffy to which each contributes. ...
>    Taffy² [An ascribed Welsh pronunciation of *Davy* or *David*, in Welsh
>   *Dafydd*.] A familiar nickname for a Welshman: cf. *Paddy, Sawney,* etc.

The half-dozen OED1 cites for *Taffy¹* sense 1 date from 1817 to 1890, and the cites for  *Toffee, toffy* from 1825 to 1896.  The [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift) occurred 1350–1700.

Comment: What does the OED say under *taffy*? It looks like the Great Vowel Shift at work, i.e. *toffee* and *taffy* are both phonetic renderings of the same word, but somewhere along the way, the pronunciation of the vowels changed.

Comment: @Marthaª, that may be, although OED1 doesn't say (see edit)